# hdfs -get folder error

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I met an error when run hdfs dfs -get command like this:

```
[work@myserver ~]$ hdfs dfs -get hdfs://hadoopserver:8020/path/DataLoad/
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.displayError(FsShell.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:340)
```

The "hadoopserver" is the master of a hadoop cluster which is not in the same network with myserver. I connect it by config public network IP in "/etc/hosts".

What's more, this error only happen when getting folder and from out network. Look 2 examples below: The first one is I get the folder from another server which is in the same network with hadoopserver. And the second example is I get a file instead of a folder from the same server(myserver). Both them succeed.

```
[work@hadoopserver_2 lewis]$ hdfs dfs -get hdfs://hadoopserver:8020/path/DataLoad ./
[work@hadoopserver_2 lewis]$ du -sh DataLoad/
 1.2G   DataLoad/

[work@myserver ~]$ hdfs dfs -get hdfs://hadoopserver:8020/path/DataLoad/part-r-00375-724f4a2e-ed40-4100-8e81-6657d9dacc01.gz.parquet ./
[work@myserver ~]$ ls
part-r-00375-724f4a2e-ed40-4100-8e81-6657d9dacc01.gz.parquet
```

To add one last point, when I get folder from outer network and get the error, the folder will always be created and sometimes get incomplete files.

```
[work@myserver DataLoad]$ ls
part-r-00000-724f4a2e-ed40-4100-8e81-6657d9dacc01.gz.parquet  _SUCCESS
[work@myserver DataLoad]$ du -sh
10M .
```

(There should be many files in DataLoad and larger than 10M. And in most times, there is only a empty file named "_SUCCESS".)

Comment: Is your host `myserver` setup as an edge node?

Comment: no,  I have tried many servers. "myserver " can be just a server with hdfs command.

Comment: could you do other operation  such as ` mkdir  put `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my workmate has solved this problem. We use  `hdfs --loglevel DEBUG` to show the detail error. The root cause is that I just config the master server ip in "/etc/hosts". When `myserver`  tried to get data from a hadoop cluster from outer network. The master server(default 8020 port)  tells me which datanode(default 50070 port) I should to connect to. So I can't get the whole folder because the file must in different datanodes. I successed to get the file maybe it just on the master node(which is the only server 
 config in my hosts).

So after I config all node's public IP in hosts. I can get the folder succeessfully.

Comment: That is correct.  HDFS provides reliability through replication (defaults to 3) so your file would be on several of the datanodes.  So you'd need to know the IP addresses of all the datanodes.